# Monitor a folder for changes, and run a command when a change is detected

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

Is there a simple way to automatically run a (Terminal) command every time a file is changed in a specific folder?

This should be possible via the command line, or a system built-in application, no third-party applications.

Any ideas?

Comment: Another dupe? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/checking-for-folder-file-changes-using-automator

Comment: And NOT a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/checking-for-folder-file-changes-using-automator because that question and answer presuppose using Automator to do it. As the discussion below shows, Automator is not up to the current task.

Answer (score 19):

[entr(1)](https://eradman.com/entrproject/) is a utility for running commands when files change. It reads a list of file on STDIN and uses [kqueue(2)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kqueue.2.html) to avoid polling.

Example:

```
ls my_project/*.html | entr echo "file changed"
```

It can be installed directly from the project site or via Homebrew.

For 2022, simply `% brew install entr` to install.

Answer (score 8):

Save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>say</string>
        <string>yy</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>~/Desktop/</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The agent can be loaded with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/test.plist` or by logging out and back in. Applying changes requires unloading and loading the plist.

Tilde expansion (`~/`) works in WatchPaths by default. EnableGlobbing adds wildcard and tilde expansion for ProgramArguments, but it doesn't affect Program or WatchPaths.

If a watched file is modified within ten seconds from the last invocation, a message like this is added to system.log:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[146]: (test) Throttling respawn: Will start in 7 seconds
```

One way to get rid of the messages is to add something like `sleep 10` to the end of scripts. Setting ThrottleInterval to 10 doesn't help.

Changes in subfolders of watched folders aren't detected.

See `man launchd` and `man launchd.plist` for more information.

Comment: This solution direction is well explained in a tutorial at https://mayeu.me/post/how-to-trigger-any-action-when-a-file-or-folder-changes-on-macos-on-the-cheap/

Answer (score 5):

Folder actions are fine for triggering when a file is added or modified.

However, if your definition of changed includes deleting a file, OSX Folder actions does not detect if a file has been removed.

**To answer the question:**

1. Download the FileWatcher dependencies from here: https://github.com/eonist/FileWatcher
2. Familiarize your self with running swift in the comandline: http://krakendev.io/blog/scripting-in-swift
3. Use this code to watch a folder.

**Code:**

```
var fileWatcher = FileWatcher(["~/Desktop/test/".tildePath])/*<---the fileWatcher instance must be scoped to your class*/

fileWatcher!.event = { event in
    Swift.print(self?.someVariable)//Outputs: a variable in your current class
    Swift.print(event.description)//Outputs: a description of the file change
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Folder Actions, which lets you execute (Automator) scripts whenever contents in a folder change. As far as I know, Automator has a template that lets you easily create a new folder action and attach it to the desired folder. And by adding a "Run Shell Script" action, you should just get the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that "Folder Actions" are only triggered when a file is added to the folder, not when an existing file is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Automator has a type of workflow called a "Folder Action" which automatically runs when something is added to a folder. Create one, then use the action "Run Shell Script."

Comment: Thanks, but it appears that "Folder Actions" are only triggered when a file is added to the folder, not when an existing file is checked.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) which claims to be "a cross-platform file change monitor", and seems to support all the proper platform solutions like Filesystem Events on macOS.

```bash
# Monitor all files in a directory, execute script once when something changes
fswatch -o -r path/to/directory | xargs -n1 -I{} your-command-here
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
touch /tmp/dirb.tmp
while true do 
  ls /thedirtocheck > /tmp/dira.tmp 
  diff /tmp/dira.tmp /tmp/dirb.tmp || echo "something changed" 
  cp /tmp/dira.tmp /tmp/dirb.tmp 
  sleep 100 
done
```

Comment: You need at least `ls -l` to catch file changes as well.

Comment: right.... missed that