# Would it be possible to create a folder action that can push timed Notifications?

Tags: macos, notifications, folder-action

Specifically I'd like to attach a folder action that would pass to the Notification center a timed alert that would go off after 60 days... possible?

Comment: What sort of action are you trying to make happen?

Comment: I want to set a 60 day reminder automatically. So, 60 days after I save or move something to the folder (with the folder action attached), a reminder notification would pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Enable `at`:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Add a Run Shell Script action that uses [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) to display a notification:

```
at 2 months <<< 'terminal-notifier -message "some message" -title "title"'
```

Replace `terminal-notifier` with `/Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier` if you've installed it by downloading the application bundle.

`now+5 <<< 'say a'` would run a command in five seconds. You can list scheduled commands with `atq` and remove them with `atrm`. See `man at` for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that's a bit advanced for me… Could you possibly break it down a little for me?

Comment: I edited the answer. You could also use [launchd](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected) instead of folder actions.

Comment: I got a little help and figured out how to modify an existing applescript I had already attached. I just needed to change a few terms. So the updated script now is: cont.

Comment: Oh crap...no way to save the formatting...

Answer (score 1):

OK so as it turns out I found the answer to this. I just needed to edit my existing attached applescript. And here is is with the proper formatting in place:

```
property myList : "Invoices"

on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    repeat with this_item in these_items
        set fName to name of (info for this_item)
        if fName does not start with "." then -- avoid new todo for .dsstore files or something similar 
            set startTime to (current date) + 60 * days
            tell application "Reminders"
                make new reminder at beginning of list myList with properties {name:fName, due date:startTime, remind me date:startTime}
            end tell
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```