# Resource efficient way to monitor file change and execute shell scripts on change

Tags: terminal, command-line

I know at least three ways to monitor a folder/file for changes and execute a shell script on change.

- First, use "Folder Actions" of Automator
- Second, the [launchd.plist approach](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected) but it seems the folder been monitored couldn't go through recursively.
- Third, use native FSEvents API on Mac OS X. like the modified [fswatch](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch) utility

My question is that which one cost system resource (CPU or memory) less ?

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that the first two rely on the third -> all are rather efficient.

Comment: Folder actions are also limited to a single folder without subfolders. And they are only run when files are added, not when they are modified.