# How to ignore changes in sub-folders of monitored folder in Launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm using launchd to detect changes of a specific path using "WatchPaths" key and then run some codes, but the content changes of sub-folders are not of interest.

For example, in order to monitor changes on my desktop, I'd add the following code in plist:

```
<key>WatchPaths</key>
<array>
    <string>~/Desktop/</string>
</array>
```

It is indeed working, but if I paste a file into a folder on the desktop, the plist is also executed, How to prevent this?

I've already looked through some posts and tutorials, but no clues at  all:

[Monitor a folder for changes, and run a command when a change is detected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected?r=SearchResults)

https://www.launchd.info/

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance.