# How to execute a Folder Action or another Automator script when I make changes to a folder?

Tags: automator, folder-action

How to execute a Folder Action or another Automator script when I make changes to a folder?
And by changes I mean not just deleting or inserting new file, the most important for me is when the content of a file is changed the action will be triggered.

Comment: Related questions: [Monitor a folder for changes, and run a command when a change is detected](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected), [Checking for folder/file changes using Automator?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/checking-for-folder-file-changes-using-automator)

Comment: You have two awesome answers. Do either help you out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using launchd, you could save a property list like this in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/ and load it with something like `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/automator_test.plist` or by logging out and back in.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>automator_test</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>     
        <string>automator</string>
        <string>/Users/username/Desktop/Test.workflow</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/username/Desktop/</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>0</integer> <!-- run at most every 0 seconds, by default 10 -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

Launchd only detects changes to files when they are saved atomically (or deleted and recreated every time they are saved). Most OS X apps perform atomic saves, but for example TextMate and vim don't.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet al test it when I get home. But will it make it automatically every time I save changes to a file inside the folder? I started to read something about launchctl not being the recommended app/service for that, but I cannot remember where I read it.

Comment: I did that and nothing is happening

Comment: I tested it again and it worked for me. Did you replace `username`? You have to `launchctl unload $path && launchctl load $path` to apply changes.

Comment: Thank you, but, it doesn't work the way I want. It does what Folder Actions does, which is triggered if I insert, move or delete something inside the folder. I edited a HTML file inside the folder and nothing happened. And it is not recursive.

Comment: You're right that it's not recursive, but it should be triggered when files are modified or files or folders are moved, deleted, or created.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of requirement goes beyond the simple `fsevents` hooks exposed as Folder Actions. I’d recommend using Paul Kim’s [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php), which will allow you to create “watch and react” rules of almost unlimited granularity and complexity.