# Constantly check folder for specific file type and run terminal command with new filename as an argument

Tags: macos, command-line, folders

I have a folder ~/Downloads

I'm checking (using [entr](https://github.com/eradman/entr)) it for .webm videos and when new file is added I need it to be converted to .mp4 BUT can't figure out the arguments passed...

```
ls . | entr handbrakecli --encoder x264 --width 700 --format av_mp4 --optimize --non-anamorphic --rate 30 -i <new_webm> -o <same_name_append_mp4>
```

Comment: This is bread and butter for Hazel which can detect new files of specific type and then pass the file to a script.https://www.noodlesoft.com

Comment: Yes, I would have thought this is exactly what Folder Actions is for.

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6658/checking-for-folder-file-changes-using-automator

Answer (score 2):

[`entr`](https://github.com/eradman/entr) is a "utility for running arbitrary commands when files change", it doesn't specifically monitor for new files (it can pass *one* new file to the command, but I couldn't get this to work reliably). You can work around this (as you did) by having `entr` monitor the directory itself, but you still need to take care of identifying which files actually are new and avoid re-processing.

```bash
cd ~/Downloads
mkdir -p videos
while :; do
  ls . | entr -dz find . -depth 1 -type f -iname "*.webm" -exec sh -c '
      f="$1"
      mv -- "$f" videos/
      handbrakecli --encoder x264 --width 700 --format av_mp4 --optimize --non-anamorphic --rate 30 -i "videos/$f" -o "videos/${f%.webm}.mp4" 
      # rm "videos/$f"
      ' _ {} \;
done
```

This uses `find` to identify new WebM files, moves them to a different directory (to avoid reprocessing) and runs Handbrake on them. Uncomment the last line to automatically remove WebM files after processing. To terminate, press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> and then run `kill -9 %1`.

PS: As @gilby already mentioned in the comments: Get [Hazel](https://noodlesoft.com), works like a charm.
PPS: Also, the answers on [Monitor a folder for changes, and run a command when a change is detected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40705/monitor-a-folder-for-changes-and-run-a-command-when-a-change-is-detected?noredirect=1&lq=1)  provide some additional ways to trigger shell scripts after the content of a directory changes.

Comment: Why buy Hazel if all can be done with one command in terminal (just can't get it to work 100% automatically)

Comment: @PavelPervoy Maybe exactly because of that? You can also use Automator to define Folder Actions.

Answer (score 0):

Changed *entr* to *fswatch*:

```
fswatch . | find . -type f -name "*.webm" -exec handbrakecli --encoder x264 --width 700 --format av_mp4 --optimize --non-anamorphic --rate 30 -i "{}" -o "{}.mp4" \;
```

Problem is - script exits after video conversion. Need to restart it each time.

Still no stable solution ;(

Comment: `while :; do YOUR CODE HERE; done` :-) But you still will reprocess all webm files each time.